# How to change a debug console default language in a Visual Studio C++?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017

I changed UI language to English, but Microsoft Visual Studio Debug Console language is Russian anyway, so I have to switch it every time. Are there any ways to fix it?

Comment: What is "Debug Console" exactly?

Comment: The window which is appears when I press F5

Comment: It is just a regular console window that prints whatever you pass to it.

Comment: I mean I write code in English, then I press F5 and try to enter something, but language changes to Russian and I have to turn it to English before.

Comment: Do you mean keyboard layout switches to russian or something else?

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm talking about!

Comment: Well, this does not happen to me. You may want to check your keyboard layout settings. Anyway, this has nothing to do with C++ and / or VS.